# MIPS store bytes

Tags: mips, store, mips32

Fairly new to MIPS and wondering if it was possible to store characters in data directives that did NOT come from user input?

I have a data directive called checking declared with .space16

checking: .space 16

I want to store a string of characters in it based off filtered lowercase characters.  Is this possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible. Look up the `sb` instruction in a MIPS instruction set reference.

Comment: Thank you i thought so too but now I have code that will not store it properly. I know MIPS is legacy like C so i wanted to make sure i wasn't trying to do anything more dynamic than was capable

Comment: You can copy an existing string literal (declared with `.asciiz "hello world"`) into the zeroed space reserved by `.space`, using a loop or other. You can also copy constants, one character at a time, e.g. copy `h` then `e`, then `l`, `l`, `o`...

Comment: I am trying to see how to vote as answered but i was able to solve it with you all's help